# Dog has occasional weakness in rear legs; seizure

Tags: dogs

My dog seems to have occasional seizures, for lack of a better term.

Seems to occur randomly and not very often; maybe 4 times in the last year that I've witnessed.

When it occurs, she appears weak in her rear legs with a little bit of shaking as she tries to walk and her eyes appear far away.

It passes very quickly, never lasting more than 10 seconds.

She's up to date on her shots, takes Nexgard and heart worm pills once a month.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take her to a vet. If possible, take a video of her having the seizure to show your vet.

Answer (score 1):

My brother-in-law's dog does something similar where her back legs shake and go limp. They realised it was an issue with her nervous system but it only happens when she get extremely worked up, be it with excitement or anger. They have since moved from a Canadian city to the Irish countryside where the dog is much more relaxed and easy going (she's a rescue terrier with tendencies to be aggressive)

Be it the air or the outside space that is making her less stressed, but the shakes don't seem to happen as frequently anymore. They had her diagnosed by the vet and all, but it wasn't impacting her life enough to put her through major surgery since it was such an infrequent, brief and non-distressing occurrence for her.

Of course, I would still get a diagnosis from an actual vet but it could be down to stress if it is frequent.